# how can I page a postrges dataset with "simplepagination.js"?

Tags: jquery, ruby, postgresql, sinatra, sequel

I am using sinatra, postgres, ruby and sequel ORM. The dataset is produced by this code:

```
 cookie = request.cookies["cookie"]
  unless cookie
      redirect '/login'
    end
user_id = users.where(:validation => cookie).get(:id)
  if params['date_from'].empty?
    search_term = params['search_term']
    call_logs.where(:call_to => search_term, :user_id => user_id).or(:call_from => search_term, :user_id => user_id).or(:call_direction => search_term, :user_id => user_id).to_a.to_json
  end
```

I am not using any particular paging extension, so this may be the first problem.

The jquery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#get_my_call_logs").click(function() {
var search_term = $("#search_term").val();
$("#results").html("");
$("#results").append('<table id="content">').addClass('tftable');
$("#results").append('<tbody>')
$("#results").append('<tr><th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Direction</th><th>Duration</th><th>Billed time</th><th>Charge</th><th>Date</th></tr>');
$.getJSON("/get_call_logs?search_term="+search_term+"&date_from="+date_from, function(data) {   
     $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
     var call_from = this["call_from"]
     from = call_from.replace("@phone.plivo.com","")
      var txt = '<tr><td>'+from+'</td>';
     var call_to = this["call_to"]
     to = call_to.replace("@phone.plivo.com","")
        txt += '<td>'+to+'</td>';
        txt += '<td>'+this["call_direction"]+'</td>';
        txt  += '<td>'+this["call_duration"]+'</td>';
        txt  += '<td>'+this["billed_duration"]+'</td>';
        txt  += '<td>'+parseFloat(this["total_charged_cost"]).toFixed(2)+'</td>';
        txt  += '<td>'+this["created_at"]+'</td></tr>';
        $("#results").append(txt);
            });
      });
      $("#results").append('</tbody>');
      $("#results").append('</table>');
      $("#results").append('<div id="pagination"></div>');
});
});
```

So far so good, now I run into problems. I am using the simplepagination plugin. And the code is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
                var items = $("#content tbody tr");

                var numItems = items.length;
                var perPage = 2;

                // only show the first 2 (or "first per_page") items initially
                items.slice(perPage).hide();

                // now setup pagination
                $("#pagination").pagination({
                    items: numItems,
                    itemsOnPage: perPage,
                    cssStyle: "light-theme",
                    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
                        // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
                        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

                        items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
                             .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
                    }
                });
            //});       
});
```

The data is printed on the html in its entirety with no paging present and no item count of 2 as specified above.

What's going wrong here guys? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i hardly recommend you [this jQuery textpager](https://github.com/dwaskowski/jquery_textpager) plugin instead.
so simple and effective!
hope to help.

Answer (score 0):

OK solved, here is the answer. It is necessary to incorporate the paging script with the json script so they work together

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#get_my_call_logs").click(function() {
$("#pagination").pagination({
itemsOnPage: 5,
        cssStyle: 'light-theme'
});
var search_term = $("#search_term").val();
var date_from = '';
$("#results").html("");
$("#results").append('<table id="content">').addClass('tftable');
$("#results").append('<tbody>')
$("#results").append('<th>From</th><th>To</th><th>Direction</th><th>Duration</th><th>Billed</th><th>Charge</th><th>Date</th>');
$.getJSON("/get_call_logs?search_term="+search_term+"&date_from="+date_from, function(data) {   
     $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
     var call_from = this["call_from"]
     from = call_from.replace("@phone.plivo.com","")
      var txt = '<tr><td>'+from+'</td>';
     var call_to = this["call_to"]
     to = call_to.replace("@phone.plivo.com","")
        txt += '<td>'+to+'</td>';
        txt += '<td>'+this["call_direction"]+'</td>';
        txt  += '<td>'+this["call_duration"]+'</td>';
        txt  += '<td>'+this["billed_duration"]+'</td>';
        txt  += '<td>'+parseFloat(this["total_charged_cost"]).toFixed(2)+'</td>';
        txt  += '<td>'+this["created_at"]+'</td></tr>';
        $("#results").append(txt);

            });
var items = $("data, tr");
        var numItems = items.length;
                var perPage = 11;
$("#pagination").pagination({
                    items: numItems,
                    itemsOnPage: perPage,
                    cssStyle: "light-theme",
                    onPageClick: function(pageNumber) { // this is where the magic happens
                        // someone changed page, lets hide/show trs appropriately
                        var showFrom = perPage * (pageNumber - 1);
                        var showTo = showFrom + perPage;

                        items.hide() // first hide everything, then show for the new page
                             .slice(showFrom, showTo).show();
                    }
      });
      $("#results").append('</tbody>');
      $("#results").append('</table>');

                });
});
$("#results").append('<div id="pagination"></div>');

});
```

I hope that this helps somebody else. It is something that has bugged me for ages.